# Apply custom low-pass filter to time domain waveform with scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, lowpass-filter

I am interested in applying a custom low-pas filter to a time domain signal using the various tools that `SciPy` provides.

I know how to apply a low-pass filter to a time domain waveform using the `Butterwoth` filter and filtering with `sosfilt` (see [scipy.signal.butter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html)). What I do not know is how to use `SciPy`'s built-in tools to apply filtering using a custom filter that I have. How can I take my filter (attenuation vs frequency measured experimentally) and process it so I can feed it to the `sosfilt` method for instance? It probably is going to take extracting the polynomials or second-order sections representation of the filter in some way but I failed finding the relevant information in the `SciPy`'s doc.

It might be something standard in signal processing but I am no expert.

For now I successfully applied "by hand" the filtering to the FFT of the time domain waveform and inversed FFT it to retrieve the filtered time domain waveform. It would be neat to not have to go the FFT route and use `sosfilt` instead.

Thanks!